# only last dynamically created picturebox is accessible

Tags: c#, dynamic, this, tabcontrol, picturebox

I am creating a win form application in which i have a **tabcontrol1**, 
and at **run time created tabpage and picturebox**

on a **button click** i **create new tab page and picture box
and addthem to the tabcontrol1.**

now i can change image of **only last created** picture box...
and when i try to change the image of any picture box except the last one, i am not able to do that

this is the code example

button1 creates new tabpage and picturebox

```
 private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        TabPage tpgallery = new TabPage();           
        tpgallery.Name = "tpgallery";
        tpgallery.Text = "  Gallery  ";            

        tabControl1.TabPages.Add(tpgallery);           

        picturebox1 = new PictureBox();           

        picturebox1.Name = "picturebox1name";           
        picturebox1.Image = WindowsFormsApplication7.Properties.Resources.logo1;

        tpgallery.Controls.Add(picturebox1);          
    }
```

button2 changes image of picturebox

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    { 
        picturebox1.Image = WindowsFormsApplication7.Properties.Resources.logo2; 
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`pictureBox1` holds the reference to the last created one, that's your problem. Try this:

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{ 
    PictureBox pb = tabControl1.SelectedTab.Controls.OfType<PictureBox>()
                       .FirstOrDefault(p=>p.Name == "picturebox1name");
    if(pb != null)
     pb.Image = WindowsFormsApplication7.Properties.Resources.logo2; 
}
```

**NOTE**: you can also use this code to get the picturebox:

```
PictureBox pb = tabControl1.SelectedTab.Controls["picturebox1name"] as PictureBox;
```

### UPDATE

If you have `tabControl2` in some `tabPage` of `tabControl1`, try this:

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{ 
    TabControl actualTabControl = tabControl1.SelectedTab.Controls.OfType<TabControl>()
                                             .FirstOrDefault();
    if(actualTabControl != null){
     PictureBox pb = actualTabControl.SelectedTab.Controls["picturebox1name"] as PictureBox;
     if(pb != null)
        pb.Image = WindowsFormsApplication7.Properties.Resources.logo2; 
    }
}
```

Comment: how can i get controls of child of selected tab actually in real my picturebox1 lies in a tabpage this tabpage lies in a tab control and this tab control lies in the selected tab page like:- static tabcontrol1 which has tabpage1 which has a tabcontrol2 which has a tabpage 2 which has a picturebox 1

Comment: @user2791184 see my update, it's just a little different from the previous code.

Answer (score 0):

This is because you are always creating a new picturebox overwriting the variable picturebox1 and so loosing the reference to all pictureboxes except the last one created.

If you click button2 you have to go to the currently active tab and search for the picturebox in the tabpages control collection and change the image there.
The result (nonoptimized) should look like this:

```
    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        { 
            PictureBox pb = null;

            foreach (Control c in tabControl1.SelectedTab.Controls)
                if (c is PictureBox)
                {
                    pb = c as PictureBox;
                    break;
                }

            pb.Image = WindowsFormsApplication7.Properties.Resources.logo2; 
        }
```

Comment: yes the image is changed at last picturebox on pressing button2
so how should i do....?
i want to change image of picturebox by button2

Comment: @user2791184 you created many pictureboxes, so which one do you want to change its image when clicking button2?

Comment: how can i get controls of child of selected tab
actually in real my picturebox1 lies in a tabpage this tabpage lies in a tab control and this tab control lies in the selected tab page

like:- static tabcontrol1 which has tabpage1 which has a tabcontrol2 which has a tabpage 2 which has a picturebox